# Issues Connecting PHPMyAdmin Database to Power BI

Tags: phpmyadmin, powerbi

I have recently setup a new database in the PHPMyAdmin tool for Inmotion hosting. I have also been successful in setting up a connection between the database and MySQL Workbench.

I am now working to try to setup a connection between this database and Power BI in order to setup some reporting on the data. However, after inputs I am getting the following error:

> Unable to Connect: We encountered an error while trying to connect.
>
> Details: Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the
>   network connection.)

To recreate the issues I am:

Get Data --> MySQL database

For server value I have tried many things such as localhost and localhost:3306. For credentials I am selecting database credentials and entering in credentials for the C-Panel.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL is not Microsoft sql database

Comment: @LelioFaieta When dealing with the desktop version, the database does not need to be Microsoft specific such as Azure.

Comment: @LelioFaieta mentioned so because your error message showed `Microsoft SQL Server` but not `MySQL`. Are you sure you've picked the correct connection?

Comment: I agree with @FoxanNg - I don't have an option `Get Data --> MySQL database`. I have `Get Data --> More --> Database --> MySQL database`, which displays "MySQL database: This connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used" with a link to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: So I think I had gone that route before as well. When taking @user5226582 route, I get the error "MySQL: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." I've also already downloaded the connector required. I have tried both localhost and localhost:3306 as the server.